# Why doesn't my program seg fault when I dereference a NULL pointer inside of malloc?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I use this malloc style all the time

```
int *rc = 0;
rc = malloc(sizeof(*rc));
```

However, it doesn't seg fault even though when I call `sizeof(*rc)` I assume that `rc==0`, and I am dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is sizeof(\*ptr) undefined behavior when pointing to invalid memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721184/is-sizeofptr-undefined-behavior-when-pointing-to-invalid-memory)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are not really dereferencing anything. The argument of `sizeof` is not evaluated, unless it is a VLA. It is explicitly allowed by the language to put whatever "garbage" you want as the argument of `sizeof`. The language guarantees that it will not evaluate anything, just perform compile-time analysis of the type of the expression. For example, expression `sizeof i++` is guaranteed not to change the value of `i`.

The only exception from that rule is Variable Length Arrays. The result of `sizeof` for VLAs is a run-time value, which means that the argument is evaluated and must be valid.

Comment: Isn't it actually unspecified what, if anything, is evaluated in the VLA case?

Comment: @R..: C99 explicitly states that it is. For example, in case of VLA `int a[n][n]`, I would expect the expression `sizeof a[i++]` to increment `i`. I don't see using `sizeof` with side effects as a good programming practice, but nevertheless in such cases it is there.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong about that. Nice clever example; in general, most expressions which could have side effects do not have VLA type (even though they may involve VLAs as operands). You pointed out one of the few examples where there's an expression with side effects whose type is a VLA type.

Answer (score 8):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't actually evaluate its operand, it only looks at its type. The type of `*rc` is `int`, so it's equivalent to `sizeof (int)`. This all happens at compile time.

(Also, this is not "inside of malloc".)

Answer (score 4):

You are not actually dereferencing a pointer, you are asking the compiler for the size of the type `rc` points to. In this case `sizeof` is resolved at compile time, when there are no pointers.

Answer (score 3):

That's equivalent to `sizeof(type of *rc)` (in other words, `sizeof(int)`), not `sizeof(data stored at the location pointed to by rc)`.  `sizeof()` works on *types*, not values.

sizeof never considers the actual data, just the type, thus there's no need (and it wouldn't make sense) to deference the pointer.