# C dynamically allocated struct object causes runtime error ("Segmentation fault (core dumped)")

Tags: c, malloc

```
struct matrix {
    int m, n;   // m rows, n columns
    int** data;
    char name[64];
};

struct matrix* alloc_matrix(const char* name, int m, int n) {
    struct matrix *mat = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
    strcpy(mat->name, name);
    mat->m = m;
    mat->n = n;
    mat->data = (int**)malloc(sizeof(m) * (m * n));
    return mat;
}

int main() {
    struct matrix* mat1 = alloc_matrix("mat1", 4, 4);
    mat1->data[0][0] = 2;    <------------------------------ This line causes the error
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I want to implement matrices. I defined a struct matrix that holds the name, rows count, columns count and data of a matix. With a function alloc_matrix I want to allocade memory for a struct object. But something goes wrong in this function, because if I want to retrieve or set data on a allocated object, I get a runtime memory error.

I hope someone has more experience with dynamic data allocation and sees the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data is being used as a two-dimension array. That is, it's an array where each element of the array is itself an array of ints.

```
mat->data = (int**)malloc(sizeof(m) * (m * n));
```

This line allocates the first array. It now has enough space to hold m*n pointers, but the pointers don't point to anything. This isn't what you wanted.

What you want is for data to hold m pointers, each of which hold n elements.

```
mat->data = (int**)malloc(sizeof(*mat->data) * m);

if(!mat->data)
{
    //handle error case
}

for(int ii = 0; ii < m; ++ii)
{
    mat->data[ii] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(**mat->data) * n);#

    if(!mat->data[ii])
    {
         //handle error case
    }
}
```

Comment: Use objects instead of types in `sizeof` when possible. It is a good practice

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else wondering, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574421/why-doesnt-my-program-seg-fault-when-i-dereference-a-null-pointer-inside-of-mal) explains why we can dereference these before we've malloc'd them.

Comment: We do not dereference them. `sizeof` happens compile time

Comment: Apologies, my comment was badly phrased. I was initially surprised by seeing what looked like a deference, until I remembered that sizeof was compile time. I linked to question to explain to anyone else who equally surprised. I'll add error checking as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

`mat->data = (int**)malloc(sizeof(m) * (m * n));` this line does not do what you think. You need to alloc space for the pointers first, then space for the referenced objects for all of allocated pointers.

## important!!! You need always to check the result of the malloc!

it has to be:

```
    if(mat->data = malloc(sizeof(*mat->data) * (m)))
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            if(!(mat->data[index] = malloc(sizeof(**mat->data) * n)))
            {
                //do something if malloc failed
            }
        }
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/skBJzb

Personally I would not do it this way in this case. I prefere personally to limit number of mallocs

```
struct matrix {
    size_t r, c;   // r rows, c columns
    char name[64];
    int data[];
};

struct matrix* alloc_matrix(const char* name, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    struct matrix *mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat) + rows * cols * sizeof(mat -> data[0]));
    if(mat)
    {
        strcpy(mat->name, name);
        mat->r = rows;
        mat->c = cols;
    }
    return mat;
}

int setdata(struct matrix *mat, size_t row, size_t col, int val)
{
    int result = -1;
    
    if(mat)
    {
        if(row < mat -> r && col < mat -> c)
        {
            mat -> data[row * mat -> c + col] = val;
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    struct matrix* mat1 = alloc_matrix("mat1", 4, 4);
    
    if(mat1)
    {
        printf("set result %d\n", setdata(mat1, 2, 2, 0));
        printf("set result %d\n", setdata(mat1, 5, 2, 0));
    }
}
```