# sizeof(*p) are my results undefined?

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof, dereference

In this code, I'm dereferencing an element that is uninitialized. Are my results undefined?

```
int x[10];
int *p = x;

cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p) << endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean _"an element that doesn't exist"_? It's right there.

Comment: Meant to say *Uninitialized.

Comment: Your result is defined but useless

Comment: It's not the same question, but actually it answers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721184/is-sizeofptr-undefined-behavior-when-pointing-to-invalid-memory

Comment: You're not dereferencing anything, because the operand expression of `sizeof` is *unevaluated*. "Dereferencing" means "to evaluate an indirection expression".

Comment: `sizeof` works at comple-time, not run-time.  The code is equivalent to `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p) << endl;
```

is perfectly legal and but not exactly valid code. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. If they can't be evaluated at compile time, you will get compiler error.

The surprise will be the expected result. You won't get `10`. To get `10`, you'll need to use:

```
cout << sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]) << endl;
```

Comment: @Slava, unfortunate but true.

Comment: @MajorasCoffee, that is correct. Since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, the only thing that matters is the type of the object, not whether it has a valid value.

Comment: @MajorasCoffee that's fine. Problem is what you trying to achieve dividing size of pointer to size of int. That barely means anything for you.

Comment: @Slava Originally I thought I was right in thinking that it would result in 4/4 but I like to double check my answers so I looked up the exercise and some guy has that the result is undefined so I was unsure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MajorasCoffee The result is implementation defined.  `sizeof(pointer)` changes depending on what system you are on.  Typically it is 4 on a 32 bit system and 8 on a 64 bit system.  Maybe that is what was meant by undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In c++, the expressions "*p" and "p[0]" evaluate the same way, so:

```
*p == p[0]
```

would evaluate to true. I don't know what you mean by "an element that doesn't exist".

I don't think your code does what you think. The line

```
cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p) << endl;
```

will evaluate sizeof(p), which is of type int*, and give something like 4, evaluate sizeof(*p), which is of type int, and give something like 4, and then divide them to give 1.

This code is perfectly valid, but since most common systems use 4 bytes for both ints and pointers, you will most likely print out "1" every time.

If you instead wrote:

```
cout << sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x) << endl;
```

or

```
cout << sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]) << endl;
```

you would get "sizeof(int[10]) / sizeof(int)", which equals 10. This is because the type of *x* is not int*, but int[10], or "an array of 10 ints".

As answered by R Sahu, sizeof() evaluates at compile-time, so if it can't figure out the size, your code will not compile.

Comment: Originally I thought I was right in thinking that it would result in 4/4 going by my book but I like to double check my answers so I looked up the exercise I was on and some guy has that the result is undefined so I was unsure. Thanks for the help :)